# Insert link only to the div's background image and not to the other elements inside div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I would like to insert a link only to the background image of the div and not to the other elements, inserting the inline css !
This is my code:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 box-home" style="background-image: url('URL-IMAGE');">

    <div id="spazio" style="height:55%;"></div>

    <div class="description" id="descr-one">
        <h2><?php the_field('titolo_il_box'); ?></h2>
        <p><?php the_field('descrizione_il_box'); ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add a link to the image of background.

If I add a tag in this mode, link all div !

```
<a href="URL">

    <div class="col-sm-4 box-home" style="background-image: url('URL-IMAGE');">

        <div id="spazio" style="height:55%;"></div>

        <div class="description" id="descr-one">
            <h2><?php the_field('titolo_il_box'); ?></h2>
            <p><?php the_field('descrizione_il_box'); ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>

</a>
```

Comment: Couldn't get you what u want to achieve.

Comment: There isn't a way to make a background image a link. You might be able to put an image in there and move it to the background using CSS positioning and z-index, but that isn't really how it's intended to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a link to background image only. You can only add links to elements, but not backgrounds.
You could possibly separate the image from background and place the text over it with position: absolute.

```css
.box-home {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.description {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-home">
  <a href="https://www.google.co.uk/" target="_blank"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dzw929a4t/image/upload/v1495721050/sample.jpg" alt="" /></a>
  <div class="description" id="descr-one">
    <h2>title</h2>
    <p>description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

on CodePen: https://codepen.io/Klara/pen/oWVMJz

Note sure if this is what you want to achieve.
This way you target the image only, but I would not recommend separating the title and description from the link target as it might be confusing for the users. From UX perspective it makes more sense to have both the image and the text as one clickable link.